# Displaying Nested Firebase Data in an Ionic Application

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm working with the Ionic Framework and Firebase to create an app but I'm running into some trouble. I can't display my data from Firebase. I'm creating a database for the courses at my school and I want to display the name of each course.

HTML interpolation seems to be the easiest method but it isn't working. I've tried TypeScript and JavaScript solutions but those confuse me.

Example (see picture): 
{{ 1.name }} should return math
{{ 2.name }} should return art

This is my first time posting on Stack Overflow and I've been trying to figure out this issue for 2 weeks now. I would appreciate any help. I've included code and a picture of my database.

[Firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNHgH.png)

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  courses: any[];

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    db.list('/courses').valueChanges()
      .subscribe(result => {
        this.courses = result;
        console.log(this.courses);
    });

  }

}
```

**home.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Banner Mobile
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let course of courses">
      {{ 1.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML code is incorrect there is no variable in the scope of `1` instead try accessing the variable `course`

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let course of courses">
      {{ course | json }} 
    </li>
  </ul>
</ion-content>
```

The JSON will allow you to see the structure of the `course` object. I believe based on your firebase structure the element you're wanting to access is `course.name`

Comment: course.name displays the name for both courses (1 & 2) but I only want to display the name for course 1, which would be "math"

Comment: You're looping through the courses, so this is the expected output, if you only want to show course 1 then you should change the query to be `db.list('/courses/1').valueChanges()` and remove the loop.